# Running Jmeter multiple independent jmx tests in parallel

Tags: ant, jmeter

I have a scenario where there are several independent jmx files, each of them has their own threadgroup etc. Using JMeter Ant script I can fire them all in sequence and collect the result in a jtl file. My challenge here is to do the same thing but fire off the tests in parallel. Please note that Include Controller is not an option since I want to use(or honor) the ThreadGroup and User Defined Variables in each jmx files.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Parallel Ant Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html) is what you're looking for.

However `<parallel>` directive is not thread safe so I wouldn't recommend to use it with JMeter Ant task and consider using i.e. command-line mode, maven plugin or custom Java class which will spawn individual JMeter tests with it.

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for details of the approaches, hope this helps to find the one which matches your environment.

Comment: As I posted the question, I had started with Parallel Ant Task. I will post how it went once I have the necessary outcome. It works locally. Thanks @Dmitri T

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ant parallel solves this problem.