# Is it possible to run 2 Jmeter Test Plans concurrently?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am currently running my Jmeter tests through Maven, with a simple "mvn verify" on the command line to kick off the test, and it works fine.

My test has two threadgroups, one that has results that I am interested in, and another that is performing other actions on the server but I DONT want these results included in the final statistics.

I am thinking that I should have two test plans, one with each threadgroup as above, and then just look at the results from the first test plan. The problem is that these two test plans need to be run concurrently to produce the desired effect.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391463/running-jmeter-multiple-independent-jmx-tests-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of experience in this area.   Here is what I know:

1. First, the jmeter-maven-plugin runs multiple .jmx projects serially,
   and not in parallel, so that's not an option.]
2. The Jenkins "matrix
   plugin" would also run serially as well.
3. It is possible that using the Gradle jmeter plugin would be able to fork 2 projects simultaneously if each were put in its own test task and you used   maxParallelForks=2 (or more).

So, if this doesn't answer your question, you could effectively solve the problem if you create 2 separate maven profiles, where each runs one of the .jmx projects (or separate thread groups) and then  have a master Jenkins job trigger 2 separate downstream jobs that run your 2 separate projects at the same time.